# send_file link not working Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm trying to download file instead of opening them in browser - file types can be different- so far i have below settings - it does nothing

**In views**

```
 <td><%= link_to "Download", download_file_path(resume) %></td>
```

**In controller**

```
  def download_file(file_path)
    mime = MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.content_type
    send_file(file_path, :type => mime, :disposition => "attachment")
  end
```

**In routes**

```
 get 'profiles/download_file'          => 'profiles#download_file' , as: :download_file
```

These settings works for nothing , page just refreshes - 
**FYI**: I'm using carrierwave for attachments

**UPDATES:** Logs Shown in console

> Started GET "/profiles/download_file.2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-18
>   19:25:23 +0500 Processing by ProfilesController#show as    Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"download_file"}

Comment: Are there any filters stopping that method from being reached? Logs would help.

Comment: @Matt i removed all the filters - still only refreshing

Comment: Post the log for the request, please?

Comment: @Matt question updated with logs - kindly have a look on that

Comment: you've only posted the beginning of the log, the renders and completion are important.

Comment: remaining are assets rendering

Comment: @Matt why it's taking function name as id - i believe here the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes don't allow an identifier for the record to be downloaded.

```
get 'profiles/:id/download_file'          => 'profiles#download_file' , as: :download_file
```

Although this should really be a member action on your resource routes.

You also don't want arguments on the controller method, you'll need to pull the id from the params:

```
def download_file
  file = Resume.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: still just refreshing

Comment: yeah , there was some other issue in my code - thanks :)